# Unable to render Table in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-hooks

I am trying to hit an api([sample response](https://slack-files.com/T04MYU6C6-F01H84GHZ45-35969524f3)) which gives list of objects and render it in a table in react. Following is my code. I am getting error as `data is not defined`

[Here is the code when I hardcoded data, the table got rendered perfectly](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-bas-tecpx?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function renderTableData() {
    return data.map((student, index) => {
        const { config, text, source_link, tab_type } = student //destructuring
        return (
            <tr key={config}>
                <td>{config}</td>
                <td>{text}</td>
                <td>{source_link}</td>
                <td>{tab_type}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
    }, []);
    return { data, loading };
}

export default function CreateTestcaseStep2() {
    const { data, loading } = useFetch(ENPOINT_URL_GOES_HERE)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
            <table id='students'>
                <tbody>
                    {renderTableData()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong as `renderTableData` function is not able get the `data` object.

Comment: Maybe fetch(..).then(response => response.json()).then(json => {...})

Comment: Also try to initialise your default data as empty array like const [data, setData] = useState({data:[]}); this way you can return ( {data.lenght > 0 && ....

Comment: Pass data to your `renderTableData()` function.

Comment: @ToddSkelton I tried that as well `{renderTableData({data})}` but it's not working throwing error `data.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderTableData` is defined **outside** your functional component and you refer to `data` variable within it, I suppose it doesn't know which `data` variable to refer to? I am surprised you didn't get an error about this.

Try passing the `data` variable as parameter to the function.

Comment: I have passed the data and I am getting this error
https://i.imgur.com/0vPPfTQ.png

Comment: @Mahesh Please console.log data first to see what you are passing

Comment: @Mahesh ah it probably happens because for the first time it is not initialized, try using `[]` in the custom hook as initial value for data

Comment: in the console the data is printed as an empty string `''` (excluding quotes)

Comment: @Mahesh this is *before* you set it to something. Use initial value of [] instead of '' in useState.

Comment: just replaced `[]` in place of `''` and the data got rendered perfectly. Thank you so much @giorgim

Comment: @Mahesh *map* is a function which should be called on array, not string

Comment: got it. Thanks... one last thing... I am getting this warning..can this be ignored?https://i.imgur.com/sA5P9qr.png or I need to handle it?

Comment: @Mahesh It is better to not ignore it, here is some reading about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: sure. Thanks for your timely help. I got little confidence now in handling data using hooks

Comment: @Mahesh you are welcome, good luck! (so the problem was before data arrived from `fetch` you were passing '' to the method).

Answer (score 0):

I'm refactor you example.

> Do not use `useEffect` asyc.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setData(response);
      setLoading(false);
    });
}, [url]);
```

> If you want to make table body with a function, need to pass data using parameters.

```
const renderTableData = (data) => {
                      // ^^^^  Pass data using function parameters, 
                      // this function it's possible to use in another table with the same data
  return data?.map((student) => {
    const { id, name, username, email } = student;
    return (
      <tr key={id}>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{username}</td>
        <td>{email}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
};
```

> To render table body with function pass state

```
<tbody>{renderTableData(data)}</tbody>
                     // ^^^^ Passing state to render table body
```

See live demo, pass data into function using params:

[image: Edit elated-hill-symxk]